# NIFI REST API: how to login with single-user-authentication

Tags: java, rest, apache-nifi

I have a NIFI 1.20.0 configured with single-user-authentication

```
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=single-user-provider
nifi.security.user.authorizer=single-user-authorizer
```

I'm using the `/nifi-api/*` endpoints through a JAVA client generated from Swagger.
However I can't find out how to authenticate the request to the APIs through the ApiClient provided.

```
ApiClient client = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient().setBasePath(configuration.url).setVerifyingSsl(false);
```

Any idea how to do it? Using `.setUsername()` and `.setPassword` raises an error saying that basic auth is not configured. Trying `.setAccessToken()` raises an error saying that OAuth is not available.

Any answer with another language client can do (Python, Go...), I'll transpose it to Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to see if you are able to get the `access token` generated through the cURL and if that works.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://<URL>/nifi-api/access/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=<USERNAME>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<PASSWORD>'
```

```py
import requests

url = "https://<URL>/nifi-api/access/token"

payload='username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I can get an access token, but I don't know how to use it (as I said `.setAccessToken()` raises an error saying that OAuth is not available)